# How to remove lines (or text in given lines) from file in batch?

Tags: batch-file

My goal is to create batch script that removes line itself (if possible) or text in given lines from files such as css file.

**css file**

```
line
199
200      /* K2START */
201      .foo { width: 1 }
202      .bar { width: 2 }
203      /* K2END */
204
```

I want to remove the text between line `200` and line `203` (including comment part). The line number could be changed because other people may add more text into the file. So my option is to find text `K2START` and `K2END` then remove text between those lines.

**batch script**

This returns `"200: /* K2START */"` which is great. But I just can't figure out how to get the line number value "200" and use it.

```
findstr /N "K2START" "%K2DIR%\K2 smartforms Designer\Styles\Themes\Sun.css"
```

I also tried to loop through each line of css file to practice loop but somehow instead of going into each line of text in the css file, the entire path string (i.e. `"%K2DIR%\K2 smartforms Designer\Styles\Themes\Sun.css"`) is treated as token.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ("%K2DIR%\K2 smartforms Designer\Styles\Themes\Sun.css") DO (
@echo %%G
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Get start and end line numbers of the unwanted section
set start=
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "K2START K2END" "smartforms Designer\Styles\Themes\Sun.css"') do (
   if not defined start (
      set start=%%a
   ) else (
      set end=%%a
   )
)

rem Copy all lines, excepting the ones in start-end section
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "smartforms Designer\Styles\Themes\Sun.css"') do (
   if %%a lss %start% echo(%%b
   if %%a gtr %end% echo(%%b
)) > newFile.css
```

Comment: This is very concise and much better than my lengthy script. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a gnu awk to run in what looks like a Microsoft environment,

```
awk -f hunter.awk file.txt
```

**hunter.awk:**

```
BEGIN   {printing=1;}
/\/* K2START \*\//      { printing=0; next; }
/\/* K2END \*\//        { printing=1; next; }
                        { if ( printing ) print; }
```

May I suggest the [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) project at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 1):

This works in GnuSed - an invaluable tool.

```
sed "/\/\* K2START \*\//,/\/\* K2END \*\//d" file.css >newfile.css
```

The syntax is like this, where d is to delete from start text to end text

sed "/start/,/end/d" file.txt

It looks messy because of the escaping of the \ and *