# I wish to delete a line in a file containing a particular word. (*KEYWORD)

Tags: batch-file

I wish to delete a line contaning a specific word (in my case it is [*KEYWORD]). Those files are having an extension '.blk'. These files are located in different subfolders in the same folder. I have written this followng code.

```
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
dir "C:\Users\XFIWSM\Desktop\batch_files\T30\*.blk /s/b > dirlist.txt
for /F %%i in (dirlist.txt) do (
    type %%i
    findstr /v "KEYWORD"
    > %%i.blk
   )
   pause
```

As per ansswer provided by Mr. Ken, i have tried with above code. But, nothing seems to work. i have created an empty file named dirlist.txt . But this file is also not being written with path of *.blk files. Also i wish to save the .blk file with same name at the same location. Therefore, i am trying to use > %%i.blk   ... Can anyone please help me, where am i going wrong ?

Comment: I've never seen the error message "System cannot find those files" on any version of Windows (or DOS before that). I also can't reproduce that error message using any combination of `type` and `findstr` I can come up with. Can you perhaps be **more specific** about the problem? Try running just the `type` portion of the command (remove the `|` and everything after it) - what error do you get?

Comment: same error "the system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: That's a different error. :-) When providing error messages here, **specifics** matter. Do you have at least one file with the `.blk` extension in `D:\Master\SPRINGBACK\DPK\T08`? If not, you can't `type` it.

Comment: Off course i do . The thing is, i have several folders inside T08 folder. Each folder contains exactly one file with .blk extension.

Comment: Then you don't have a `.blk` file in that folder; you have a `.blk` file in each subfolder. **Specifics are important**, both in asking your question and in reading comments or answers to it. :-) A folder *beneath* that folder is not *in that folder*; it's in a subfolder of it.

Comment: @KenWhite sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: No inconvenience. :-) I'm trying to help you, and one of the things that will help is learning to be specific and accurate regarding the details of your problem. The more easily we can understand the problem, the quicker you can get an answer that helps you solve it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `type` on files that aren't in the specified directory the way you are (your files are in *subfolders* of the specified directory, not in the directory itself).

My suggestion would be to use a `dir` command, with the appropriate switches to search subdirectories (`/s`) and to produce a bare listing (without sizes, dates, and folder/volume names) (`/b`), and redirect that to a text file. You can then use a `for /f` loop to read each line in that directory listing and process it further.

```
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
dir "D:\Master\SPRINGBACK\DPK\T08\*.blk /s/b > dirlist.txt
for /F %%i in (dirlist.txt) do (
  :: Process each file here
)
```

For information about removing a specific line of text from a file, you can see [How to remove lines (or text in given lines) from file in batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17126655)

Answer (score 0):

if you have a machine with grep, (checkout unxutils on sourceforge if using windows), you could use this commmand:
grep "KEYWORD" -v *.blk > filewithlineremoved.blk

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with "System cannot find those files"?